# Make Salesperson ID a Required field on SOLine

Tags: acumatica

I need to make Salesperson ID on SOLine as a required field. But as Transfer orders do not have Salesperson, hence it should only validate when I create orders other than Transfer orders.

I tried with below code but it seems it is not working. Might be it is overrided with some existing code. Let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

```html
public PXSetup<SOOrderTypeOperation,
 Where<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrderType.orderType>>,
 And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, Equal<Optional<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>>> sooperation;
   
protected bool IsTransferOrder
{
 get
 {
  return (sooperation.Current.INDocType == INTranType.Transfer);
 }
}

protected virtual void SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
 var row = (SOLine)e.Row;
 if (row == null) return;

 PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<SOLine.salesPersonID>(sender, row, IsTransferOrder ? PXPersistingCheck.Nothing : PXPersistingCheck.Null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually thrown an appropriate exception in Row Persisting when the condition exists.

Here is an example from SOShipmentEntry checking for transfer and checking the null value of a field:

```
protected virtual void SOShipment_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    SOShipment doc = (SOShipment)e.Row;
    if (doc.ShipmentType == SOShipmentType.Transfer && doc.DestinationSiteID == null)
    {
        throw new PXRowPersistingException(typeof(SOOrder.destinationSiteID).Name, null, ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, typeof(SOOrder.destinationSiteID).Name);
    }
}
```

I have also called RaiseExceptionHandling similar to this example within RowPersisting

```
// sender = PXCache
if (row.OrderQty == Decimal.Zero)
    sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<POLine.orderQty>(row, row.OrderQty, new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.POLineQuantityMustBeGreaterThanZero, PXErrorLevel.Error));
```

Both examples should stop the page from the save. calling the Raise Exception handling should point out the field with the Red X which is the better approach and easier for the user to find the field in question.

For your example:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
    if (row == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!IsTransferOrder && row.SalesPersonID == null)
    {
        sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.salesPersonID>(row, row.SalesPersonID, new PXSetPropertyException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXErrorLevel.Error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brendan, that helped. However, I also wanted to display that red asterisk which shows mandatory field to the user. Below code helps in that case 
`PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<SOLine.salesPersonID>(Transactions.Cache, null, IsTransferOrder ? PXPersistingCheck.Nothing : PXPersistingCheck.Null);`

Comment: Good point for red asterisk. Hope this helped some. If you want to get SetPersitingCheck to work, try moving it to RowSelected of SOOrder

Comment: Yes you are right, I have already placed in RowSelected of SOOrder