# Customer Order Required on Non-Transfer Orders

Tags: acumatica

We have a simple customization that makes the Customer Order field required. But we do not know how to prevent the requirement on Transfer-type orders, which hides the Customer Order field. I found a similar article ([Make Salesperson ID a Required field on SOLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353360/make-salesperson-id-a-required-field-on-soline)) that discusses excluding a requirement for a "line" field, but I think this scenario (preventing requirement of Customer Order field for Transfer Sales orders) might be even simpler. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change PXDefaultAttribute/PXUIFieldAttribute based on your business rules in SOOrder RowSelected event handler of SOOrderEntry graph extension:

```
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
      SOOrder soOrder = e.Row as SOOrder;

      if (soOrder != null)
      {
        bool isRequired = (soOrder.OrderType != SOOrderTypeConstants.TransferOrder);

        PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>(sender,
                                                                        soOrder, 
                                                                        isRequired ? PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank : PXPersistingCheck.Nothing);

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>(sender, isRequired);
      }
    }
  }
```